# Using the domain per space feature in openatrium

Tags: dns, spaces, open-atrium

Openatrium now has a feature for assigning a domain name to a space:

Each Space includes an option for a Domain:
"Custom domain name for this space, e.g. myspace.example.com. Do not include the http://"

This all sounds very user-friendly, but I cant find any clue anywhere how to set up.

I have a registered domain that I enter into the field and nothing happens.

I reassign the domain with my ISP to the space page, and it just goes to that url.  I try to create an alias but OA only lets you create an alias relative to the primary instal, not relative to any additional domains that may be assigned to spaces.

This does not seem to be mentioned in any of the documentation, nor in anyone else's questions anywhere.

The answer may be so mind bogglingly simple, but you would think there would be a trace of what that is somewhere!

Any thoughts welcome....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers for this is now in the documentation page.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2401483

Be sure your domain/sub-domain are pointing to the same code on your host server.

Go to admin/openatrium/setting and enter your base domain (this I missed the first time).

Create one or more Spaces, and at the Space creation page fill in a custom domain name for the space, e.g. myspace.example.com. Do not include the http://

Clear cache in each subdomain, you need to log in again for each subdomain